# Motion Planing Library + Visualization-App for 6 axis robots?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

is there any Motion Planing Library + Visualization-App for 6 axis robots out there in the Ros-Universe?

Thanks in advance
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46219/motion-planing-library-+-visualization-app-for-6-axis-robots?/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/MoveIt!) is probably what you are looking for for a motion planning library.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0